# Where Safari Web Clips are saved?

Tags: safari, widgets, dashboard

In which location Safari saves a web-clip generated widget ?

Answer (score 1):

The Web Clips are stored in this folder:

```
user/yourusername/library/preferences/widget-com.apple.widget.web-clip.plist
```

This should contain all settings and info about the widget

Comment: Path starts with `/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/`

Comment: Each widget instance is uniquely identified in that `plist` by a UUID. All its preferences have the same UUID prefix. So if you have two or more web clip widgets, they're all in there somewhere.